# Why subsetting of the data frame not working?

Tags: r

```
q <- p.adjust(tframe$p, "fdr")
CpGId <- dimnames(bmiqbeta.m)[[1]]
DF <- data.frame(CpGId, tframe$t, tframe$p, q)
dimnames(DF)[[2]] <- c("CpGId", "t", "p-value", "q")
DFred <- DF[DF$q < 0.05]
```

Initially I have tframe, a data frame with two columns namely t and p.
Then as it is evident from code, I calculated p.adjust for tframe's p values. Then I created a new data frame "DF", but I wanted to change the names of columns of  DF, so I changed them respectively. But now I want to do some subsetting of the DF but it's not working and shows the error
`Error in [.data.frame(DF, DF$q < 0.05) : undefined columns selected`

Also if I try to view the values of column p-value by using command `View(DF$p-value)`, it shows error as `object values not found`

Comment: `DFred <- DF[DF$q < 0.05, ]`

Comment: The name is `p-value` not `p-values`. You also might want to avoid `-` in names. Use underscore instead

Comment: I have mentioned another error, could you please look at that? Why the name seems not to be working?

Comment: Inspite of the p-value or p-values, it shows the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#for your first error
DFred <- DF[DF$q < 0.05, ] 
# for second error
View(DF$p-values)
```

Comment: With the second error as u mentioned in the comments before, the R seems not to accept - in names and underscores work fine with the name

Comment: Indeed. `_` and `.` are the characters of choice to include in colnames